# PHP ssh2_scp_send sometimes fails

Tags: php, upload

I'm using ssh2_scp_send to send one file from server1 to server2.

It works almost 80% of the times, but sometimes fails and I can't find any log message and i don't know why!

the command only return one bool value saying if it was sucessfull.

[ssh2_scp_send](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php)

Where can I find some log message or any of you had one similar problem?

Thanks,
Pedro
@pedro

Comment: I am having this problem as well, but my error reporting is turned on and isn't helpful. All it says is that it failed to copy the file. How did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the PHP error log is defined with "error_log" in PHP.ini. In your PHP script you should display all errors during development.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You can also choose to show errors in the PHP output.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

There is an alternative shown on:
http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php#82927

That may give you more flexible error handling.

Comment: What you all think, does the command have any concurrency restriction?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was not displaying the errors, after the ini_set(...) I was able to spot the problem. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

PHP SSH2 is a probably a wrapper around the "libssh2", so if you are looking for logs then check your syslog config file, if ssh logging is not enabled in there then ssh logs the activity in apache log files. Logs are generally stored in /var/log

One good debugging technique would be to enable logging in php.ini

```
log_errors = On
error_log = /path/to/logfile.log
```

Comment: I check the log of php and the syslog but nothing. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`ssh2_scp_send` fails for me if the file size is more then 2 GiB, it uploads 2 GiB and then stops.